# Error in linking external libraries

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I downloaded TripleBit's source code from http://grid.hust.edu.cn/triplebit/TripleBit.tar.gz.
It required me to install two libraries:

```
i)  boost-1.39.0.tar.gz
ii) raptor-1.4.21.tar.gz
```

I installed them using :

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
sudo apt-get install libraptor-dev
```

However, after I entered into TripleBit's directory and ran "make". I go the following errors:

```
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:38: undefined reference to `raptor_init'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:39: undefined reference to `raptor_new_parser'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:40: undefined reference to `raptor_set_statement_handler'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:42: undefined reference to `raptor_uri_filename_to_uri_string'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:43: undefined reference to `raptor_new_uri'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:44: undefined reference to `raptor_uri_copy'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:45: undefined reference to `raptor_parse_file'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:47: undefined reference to `raptor_free_parser'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:48: undefined reference to `raptor_free_uri'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:49: undefined reference to `raptor_free_uri'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:50: undefined reference to `raptor_free_memory'
/home/TripleBit/BuildTripleBitFromRDF/BuildTripleBit.cpp:52: undefined reference to `raptor_finish'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/lrelease/buildTripleBitFromRDF] Error 1
```

The library files which reside within /usr/local/lib are:

```
libboost_filesystem.so, libraptor.a, libraptor.la, libraptor.so, libraptor.so.1 
and libraptor.so.1.2.0
```

Also the files which reside within /usr/lib are:

```
libraptor.a, libraptor.la, libraptor.so, libraptor.so.1, libraptor.so.1.2.0, 
libraptor2.so.0, libraptor2.so.0.0.0, librasqal.so.3, librasqal.so.3.0.0, librdf.so.0, 
librdf.so.0.0.0, librest-0.7.so.0, librest-0.7.so.0.0.0.
```

Can someone please help me in finding out the error.

I ran it on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into TripleBit Makefile. You are missing -lraptor linker option. This entry should be returned by raptor-config --libs.
You can also run nm tool against libraptor.a file and check if it wasn't compiled with RAPTOR_DISABLE_V1 option.

Answer (score 1):

Look into TripleBit Makefile, you can remove the "BuildTripleBitFromRDF" in line 82(modules := ..), so that you can escape the errors, but the "BuildTripleBitFromRDF" will not build into the executables. So when the dataset you download is a RDF dataset, You can use raptor to convert RDF dataset into N3 dataset, and then use the buildTripleBitFromN3 tool to go on.
The probable problem is the wrong installing in raptor.